# Nginx not showing railsapp but instead showing Plesk default page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, plesk

I've been trying to get my vps to run my railsapp according to this tutorial: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

The setup is to make a deploy server where I can deploy my rails app thru using ssh. Much like deploying to Heroku would go.

At this point everything seems to be running without any errors. 
Nginx shows this.

```
deploy@localhost:~$ sudo service nginx status
[sudo] password for deploy: 
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-04-16 21:06:26 CEST; 11h ago
  Process: 1670 ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1666 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry TERM/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1677 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1674 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1680 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3
   Memory: 7.0M
      CPU: 69ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1680 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           ├─1681 nginx: worker process                           
           └─1682 nginx: worker process                           

Apr 16 21:06:26 localhost systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 16 21:06:26 localhost systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

But for some reason in the browser when I go to the ip-address of my server I get a default page by Plesk. Which a standard web platform installed on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I reckon that /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default must be where the problem might be. This is how looks like now:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/palazon/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Then I found that there's also /etc/nginx/sites-available/default which would normally show the default nginx page. This is how it looks like:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

   #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

And finally this is what /etc/nginx/nginx.conf shows:

```
user deploy;

worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
#       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

       # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##


        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Does someone know how I keep getting the Plesk default page. My rails app has already been successfully deployed thru capistrano: cap production deploy

I've seen that all my app files are on the server. So there's just one final link missing and I haven't been able to find it yet. Does someone know what it is?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change configs, you must restart service, to apply changes.
I also preferencji to use local DNS and nginx's blocks (equivalent to apache's virtual hosts), so you can run multiple sites.

Comment: I've been restarting ninx with 'sudo service nginx restart', but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

And how would go about using local DNS and nginx blocks?

Comment: All you need to do, is use static DNS entries in your hosts files which are targeting to your dev server. And then add some blocks with corelating name.

Answer (score 0):

As per Ubuntu (or Debian) Apache and Nginx config structure, to activate a domain configuration, you should have it in `/sites-enabled/`.
Usually there are symbolic links to the same config file in `/sites-available/`:

```
# ls -la /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Sep 17  2016 example.com.conf -> ../sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Then you will most likely to have permissions issues. Make sure that your `./public` directory is accessible for nginx user.

Plesk Onyx is shipped with Ruby on Rails, Passenger and PostgeSQL. You can adapt this instruction to perform all actions via Plesk GUI. I would suggest starting from scratch with the following action plan:

1. Make sure that you are on Plesk Onyx and necessary components are installer (i.e. nginx, Ruby, Posgre). Update/install if needed.
2. Create Gemfile and installation scripts for Capistrano. You will find the video example of RoR application deployment here - https://www.plesk.com/extensions/ruby/.
3. Most likely you will find that your Nginx configuration is ready to go. Otherwise, I suggest adding necessary directives in **Apache and Nginx Settings > Additional Nginx Directives**, minding the directives that is already exists in global configuration. It will do a simple syntax check for you.
4. Create a database and then set connection strings in the application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm all for the least painful solution. If that's Plesk Onyx then I'll do that. I only don't have a clue how to get onto their GUI. I've been solely using my terminal (mac) and ssh to configure my vps. Could you tell me how you get on there?

Comment: How do I check that ./public directory is accessible for nginx user?

Comment: Run # plesk login command via SSH under root. This will give you one-time login link. Paste it to browser address bar. Then review you admin credentials and create a domain.

Comment: Public folder should be at least readable for `www-data` user or group. When Ruby app is deployed via Plesk, your public directory will be located inside virtual host directory with it's own dedicated system user, so additional actions would not be required.

Comment: I did that but the connection times out. I think there's something wrong on Plesk.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this login issue with Plesk?

Comment: Connection timeout most likely means that port 8443 is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? I've googling but I see a lot different stuff and I don't know what is what.

Comment: Ok I got in. I'll continue with you recommended me.